# Difference between gem and require (require open-uri)

Tags: ruby, gemfile

I just wanted to understand for my self.

I'm using the nokogiri gem (for parsing HTML). If I got it right to open URLs I need to use a method from the gem 'open-uri'.

But when I include it in my Gemfile (on Windows developer's machine):

`gem 'open-uri'` - there is an error while bundle install that it can not find gem.

So If I use `require 'open-uri'` - its working.

So can some explain what is going on?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) for your gem dependecies and you're doing it right but [OpenUri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) is part of the Ruby standard library. That's why you *only* need to require it if you want to use it in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Where it is the best to requre 'open-uri' in gemfile or somewhere else?

Comment: Generally you should require it on the top of the file where you're going to use the library. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: CAREFUL: open-uri considered lethal: https://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html

Comment: Great info on open-uri here: https://janko.io/improving-open-uri/

Answer (score 9):

`require` is used to load another file and execute all its statements. This serves to import all class and method definitions in the file. `require` also keeps track of which files have been previously required so it doesn't execute it twice.

A RubyGem is a software package, commonly called a “gem”. Gems contain a packaged Ruby application or library. The RubyGems software itself allows you to easily download, install, and manipulate gems on your system.
 - [What is a Gem?](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/):

The Gemfile is then used by [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to install the specified gems.

open-uri is not a gem but part of the Ruby Standard Library so it just needs to be required.

Comment: Thanks. Where it is the best to requre 'open-uri' in gemfile or somewhere else?

Comment: If you are only using it in one place i would suggest right before the call or perhaps at the beginning of the function or file.